# Pre-image of a join of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi : G \longrightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism. Suppose that $W\leq H$ and let $x\in H$ such that $x= \phi(g)$ for some $g\in G$. I would think that the following relation holds, though I'm not sure $$\phi^{-1}\left( \langle\, W, \phi(g) W\phi(g^{-1})\rangle \right) = \langle \phi^{-1}(W), g \phi^{-1}(W)g^{-1}\rangle $$

My attempt on proving this so far is: Using the fact that $\phi (\langle H,K\rangle ) = \langle \phi(H), \phi(K) \rangle$ and $\phi(\phi^{-1}(W)) = W$, we get that $$\phi^{-1}\left( \langle\, W, \phi(g) W\phi(g^{-1})\rangle \right) = \phi^{-1}\left( \phi(\langle\phi^{-1}(W), g \phi^{-1}(W)g^{-1}\rangle \right)$$

and thus $\langle\phi^{-1}(W), g \phi^{-1}(W)g^{-1}\rangle \leq \phi^{-1}\left( \langle\, W, \;\phi(g) W\phi(g^{-1})\rangle \right)$

For the reverse inclusion, let $y\in \phi^{-1}\left( \langle\, W, \;\phi(g) W\phi(g^{-1})\rangle \right)$, then $\phi(y) \in \langle\, W, \;\phi(g) W\phi(g^{-1})\rangle$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: The conjugation by $g$ is not really relevant. For any $W,X \le H$ it is true that $\phi^{-1}(\langle W, X \rangle) = \langle \phi^{-1}(W),\phi^{-1}(X) \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general result that you could use here is that if $A,B \le G$ with $\phi(A)=\phi(B)$ and $K := \ker \phi$, then $KA=KB$. So if $K\le A$ and $K \le B$, then $A=B$.

Comment: I tried to prove the general result, $\phi^{-1}( \langle W, X \rangle) = \langle \phi^{-1}(W), \phi^{-1}(X) \rangle$. Again,  $\langle \phi^{-1}(W), \phi^{-1}(X) \rangle \leq \phi^{-1}( \langle W, X \rangle)$. I still don't know how to get the other inclusion and I'm not sure how to use your general result that you proposed now.

Comment: The two groups that you are trying to prove equal have the same image under $\phi$.